# ARKit - World Origin

Tags: swift, arkit

I need to perform an action after ARKit's world origin loads. Is there any event that is triggered after world origin loads. Or any other way?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since ARKit 1.5 you can [set the worlds origin](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2942278-setworldorigin)

```
func setWorldOrigin(relativeTransform: matrix_float4x4)
```

You can set for example the world origin to the device's position, this is also done by default when the scene loads. After you have set the world origin with the code given above you are sure the world origin is set and loaded.